# Laravel pagination show results on pages

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

So I just started working with [Laravel Pagination](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination) and I'm trying to show results of my database on the pages. In my table, I have the results linked to page_id's and they are linked to a main id. So to get the amount of pages I need, I check how many pages are linked with the main ID.

Like so:

```
$query = DB::table('table')->where('main','a value');
$paginate = $query->simplePaginate(1);
```

This outputs 2 pages and that's the right behaviour because I have 2 page_id's linked to the main ID.

Now I try to get the results to show on the pages they are meant to be on. I do it like this:

```
$get = $query->get();

foreach($get as $something){
   $array[]=  DB::table('page_results')->where('page_id', $something->page_id)->get();
}
```

Now here's the problem. On the first page, it shows every result even if it's not linked to page 1, but on the second page it shows the results it should show. For example, I have 2 results linked to the first page and 2 to the second. The first page shows 4 results(results of both pages) and the second one shows 2 results(The right results).

The pagination in my view is the same as in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination) but with different variables(Documentation code):

```
<?php foreach ($users as $user): ?>
    <?php echo $user->name; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php echo $users->links(); ?>
```

**I do not show the results in this yet but in a var_dump in my model**

```
var_dump($array);
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am extremely confused.

Comment: why not get the result from the paginator object?

Comment: @itachi because I dont need the result from the query I use the pagination on. I use a column from the pagination query result, on the query I want to show the result from.

Comment: can you tell what you are trying to do? i am a bit confuse about your approach.

Comment: @itachi I've got the pagination query and the amount of pages is working. I now try to get whatever I want on the pages on the pages. So I use the query to check the page_id on the result table. So basically it has to show the results(from another table) that belongs to the page_id from the paginate query/table.

Comment: _I now try to get whatever I want on the pages on the pages._ this is what confuses me as i can see, there are 2 different page entities here. let's say you have 10 pages. what do you want to do with that count? is there parent and child page?

Comment: @itachi I dont use count. I use the foreach on my first query. My first query is basically: Show everything from the table where the main_id=Input::get('main_id');

In that table I have pages linked to the main_id so it will always show the right amount of pages. I tested it.

Comment: @itachi There is no parent and child page. I dont use paginate on the second query. I just need to get the results on the right page though.

Answer (score 0):

simply use paginate function of laravel in repository

return $this->makeModel()->paginate(10);

and in view page

use render
 {!! $articles->render() !!} to add pagination